# Elegant way to enter many tabs in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, printing, tabs

I need to generate a string with 6 tabs in the right and 6 tabs in the left. As you can see, this is the head of my report:

```
print('\t' + '\t' + '\t' + '\t' + '\t' +'\t' +  "MY REPORTS PRESENTATION HEAD" + '\t' + '\t' + '\t' + '\t' + '\t' + '\t',file=report)
```

In Python, how do i put 6 tabs in elegant way? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "\t" * 6 try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this,

```
def header_print(*args, num_tabs: int = 6):
    print('\t' * num_tabs, *args, '\t' * num_tabs)

header_print("MY REPORTS PRESENTATION HEAD")    
header_print("MY REPORTS SUB HEAD", num_tabs=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.center`:

```
>>> s = "MY REPORTS PRESENTATION HEAD"
>>> repr(s.center(len(s) + 12, '\t'))
'\t\t\t\t\t\tMY REPORTS PRESENTATION HEAD\t\t\t\t\t\t'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string formatting as well:

```
print("{:^75}".format("My Reports Presentation"))
```